# regular expression for starting character sequence mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql, regex

I require a regular expression that selects a column from table, if it starts with a specific character sequence specified by the user.

example if i type in A i should get

Apple
Apricot
Acorn

if i type in Ab

Abba
Abdomen

etc..

This is for a query done in mysql 5.1

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regex for this, use LIKE:

```
SELECT * from my_table WHERE name LIKE 'A%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ... WHERE fieldname REGEXP '^Ab';
```

[details here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html). But if you're doing purely "start of string" matching, then use `.. LIKE 'Ab%'`, which is somewhat more efficient and can use indexes. If you need to search for any field which has a word anywhere in it that starts with `Ab`, then by all means use regexes: `REGEXP '[[:<:]Ab'`

Answer (score 0):

The regex portion of it would be:

```
'^yourCharacterSequenceHere'
```